# Browser GREEN BAR without SSL

Tags: javascript, ssl, web, ssl-certificate

I like very much the green bar that appear on SSL websites. How can i create a similary green bar without paying a SSL Certificate? Is this possible?

I've tried a JavaScript code from http://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/code-to-enable-green-bar.htm but it doesn't work.

Please do not -1 me... I'm a new user and I don't know very well how can I ask questions here...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of the green bar is to show the user that the site has been verified by a trusted Certificate Authority.

You're asking to defeat the foundation of all internet security.